# feedback and improvements for London Autos ERD

Tags: database-design, erd

> London Autos has several locations within London and its surroundings, from its humble beginning a decade ago in an east London garage, the business has expanded into a multi-million-pound business. Their main business is selling Cars both new and used, Car parts and accessories. The Cars on sale could either be by finance or customers may choose to pay by themself. Those who choose to pay are usually the top-end customers who have the habit of changing cars whenever new models are released by the manufacturer while their old cars are returned to the company for reselling to other buyers interested in used cars. London Autos has kept most of its records in a flat file in a central location. The following records are kept.
>
> Car name, model number, description, make, manufacturing date, and other necessary information. The car accessories on sale are seat covers, wheel covers, floor covers, car manual locks, and many more. All other records kept are all the information for customers, Sales Agents, purchases, and many more is kept in flat Excel files, but this has grown astronomically over the years. It has now become absolutely necessary to use a relational database to keep these records and other business transactions for London Autos.

What are feedback and improvements for the ERD (Entity-Relationship Diagram) I have designed?

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3giTy.png)

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how you are 1st stuck/unsure, following what published method? PS [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) An ERD is an image of DDL--text. [ask] [Help]

Comment: What exactly are you "confused" about?

Comment: Customer - purchases car & accessories (this is a sale) - an invoice is created for the sale - and, payment is made for the invoice. A sales agent makes the sale. This is a common concept involving customers, products and invoicing.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. But your comment hasn't addressed the issues in my earlier comments. Please act on them.